# Trouble running ORC JIT llvm-hs examples

Tags: haskell, llvm, nix, nixos

Dear StackOverflow Haskellers:

I tried asking this same question in reddit r/haskell but sadly I got no answers at all. I hope it does better here.

Maybe the answer is that [llvm-hs](https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs) isn't used that much. If you have experience using llvm with haskell, but don't use llvm-hs, I'd love to see how you use it.

I'm trying to run basic [llvm-hs](https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs) ORC JIT functionality, which has taken me to try and run the orc example of [llvm-hs-examples](https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs-examples). So far I've been unsuccessful in multiple ways (out of the four examples only the first one, basic, runs):

1. Trying to run examples with the shell.nix in https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs.git
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs-examples.git
$ cd llvm-hs
$ nix-shell shell.nix
$ cd ../llvm-hs-examples
$ cabal new-build
$ cabal run orc
```

which produces:

```sh
$ cabal run orc
Up to date
; ModuleID = 'basic'
source_filename = "<string>"

define i32 @add() {
entry:
  ret i32 42
}

JITSymbolError ""
Eager JIT Result:
()
```

2. doing a default.nix a la haskell.nix and running with nix-build

llvm-hs-examples/default.nix:

```hs
let
  examplesOverlays = [ (self: super: {
    llvm-config = self.llvm_9;
  }) ];
in
{ # Fetch the latest haskell.nix and import its default.nix
  haskellNix ? import (builtins.fetchTarball "https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/archive/ef6ca0f431fe3830c25cb2d185367245c1cce894.tar.gz") {}
  # haskellNix ? import (builtins.fetchTarball "https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/archive/c88f9eccc975b21ae1e6a6b8057a712b91e374f2.tar.gz") {}
  # haskellNix ? import (builtins.fetchTarball "https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/archive/master.tar.gz") {}

# haskell.nix provides access to the nixpkgs pins which are used by our CI,
# hence you will be more likely to get cache hits when using these.
# But you can also just use your own, e.g. '<nixpkgs>'.
, nixpkgsSrc ? haskellNix.sources.nixpkgs-2003

# haskell.nix provides some arguments to be passed to nixpkgs, including some
# patches and also the haskell.nix functionality itself as an overlay.
, nixpkgsArgs ? haskellNix.nixpkgsArgs

# import nixpkgs with overlays
, pkgs ? (import nixpkgsSrc (nixpkgsArgs // { overlays = nixpkgsArgs.overlays ++ examplesOverlays;}))
# , pkgs ? import nixpkgsSrc nixpkgsArgs
}: pkgs.haskell-nix.project {
  # 'cleanGit' cleans a source directory based on the files known by git
  src = pkgs.haskell-nix.haskellLib.cleanGit {
    name = "examples";
    src = ./.;
  };
  # For `cabal.project` based projects specify the GHC version to use.
  # compiler-nix-name = "ghc884"; # Not used for `stack.yaml` based projects.
}
```

in llvm-hs-examples's directory ran:

```sh
$ nix-build -A examples.components.exes.orc
$ ./result/bin/orc
; ModuleID = 'basic'
source_filename = "<string>"

define i32 @add() {
entry:
  ret i32 42
}

JITSymbolError ""
Eager JIT Result:
()
```

which is the same output as before.

3. I believe the last (2) approach uses stack to build, but also tried manually with stack:

a) first failed approach:

In a nix-shell with llvm-config (I used the one in llvm-hs and the one I created with haskell.nix, but same result):

```sh
$ llvm-config --version
9.0.1
$ stack build examples:orc
No packages found in snapshot which provide a "llvm-config" executable, which is a build-tool dependency of llvm-hs
llvm-hs > configure
llvm-hs > [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /run/user/1000/stack-2e6b46f4d38b8260/llvm-hs-9.0.1/Setup.hs, /run/user/1000/stack-2e6b46f4d38b8260/llvm-hs-9.0.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/Main.o )
llvm-hs > [2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/hhefesto/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /run/user/1000/stack-2e6b46f4d38b8260/llvm-hs-9.0.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
llvm-hs > Linking /run/user/1000/stack-2e6b46f4d38b8260/llvm-hs-9.0.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup ...
llvm-hs > setup: The program 'llvm-config' version ==9.0.* is required but it could not
llvm-hs > be found.
llvm-hs >
```

b) build-successful stack approach I also tried with stack's nix integration explicitly specifying llvm-config as part of buildInputs:

stack.yaml

```yaml
# resolver: nightly-2020-01-30
resolver: lts-14.0
packages:
- '.'

extra-deps:
- llvm-hs-9.0.1
- llvm-hs-pure-9.0.0
- llvm-hs-pretty-0.9.0.0

flags:
  llvm-hs:
    shared-llvm: true

nix:
  enable: true
  shell-file: stackShell.nix
```

stackShell.nix:

```hs
let
  examplesOverlays = [ (self: super: {
    llvm-config = self.llvm_9;
  }) ];
in
{ haskellNix ? import (builtins.fetchTarball "https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/archive/ef6ca0f431fe3830c25cb2d185367245c1cce894.tar.gz") {}
, nixpkgsSrc ? haskellNix.sources.nixpkgs-2003
, nixpkgsArgs ? haskellNix.nixpkgsArgs
, pkgs ? (import nixpkgsSrc (nixpkgsArgs // { overlays = nixpkgsArgs.overlays ++ examplesOverlays;}))
}:
with pkgs;
haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  name = "llvm-hs";
  buildInputs = [ llvm-config
                ];
  inherit ghc;
}
```

Which was able to build successfully, but same error:

```sh
$ stack build examples:orc                                                                                                                                       ghc-shell-for-examples
examples> configure (exe)
Configuring examples-1.0.0.0...
examples> build (exe)
Preprocessing executable 'orc' for examples-1.0.0.0..
Building executable 'orc' for examples-1.0.0.0..
examples> copy/register
Installing executable orc in /home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin
Installing executable basic in /home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin
Installing executable arith in /home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin
Installing executable irbuilder in /home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin

$ /home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin/orc        ghc-shell-for-examples
; ModuleID = 'basic'
source_filename = "<string>"

define i32 @add() {
entry:
  ret i32 42
}

JITSymbolError ""
Eager JIT Result:
()
```

A weird thing worth noting is that stack was unable to find what it had just built with `stack exec examples:orc`:

```sh
$ stack exec examples:orc
Executable named examples:orc not found on path: ["/home/hhefesto/src/llvm-hs-examples/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin","/home/hhefesto/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/2bab12248a943811dbc5aa23a88b887ce7aef1939551d21b69d96e3f64bfcbd7/8.6.5/bin","/home/hhefesto/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-linux-nix/ghc-8.6.5/bin","/nix/store/9wvsbqr57k9n6d8vv6b10d04j51f9ims-ghc-8.6.5/bin","/nix/store/4xb9z8vvk3fk2ciwqh53hzp72d0hx1da-bash-interactive-4.4-p23/bin","/nix/store/9wvsbqr57k9n6d8vv6b10d04j51f9ims-ghc-8.6.5/bin","/nix/store/m6h7zh8w6s52clnyskffj5lbkakqgywn-gcc-wrapper-9.2.0/bin","/nix/store/b3zsk4ihlpiimv3vff86bb5bxghgdzb9-gcc-9.2.0/bin","/nix/store/0k65d30z9xsixil10yw3bwajbdk4yskv-glibc-2.30-bin/bin","/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/bin","/nix/store/n48b8n251dwwb04q7f3fwxdmirsakllz-binutils-wrapper-2.31.1/bin","/nix/store/hrkc2sf2883l16d5yq3zg0y339kfw4xv-binutils-2.31.1/bin","/nix/store/0k65d30z9xsixil10yw3bwajbdk4yskv-glibc-2.30-bin/bin","/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/bin","/nix/store/6dacwd7ldb2jazc218d11v2w2g55hba8-pkg-config-0.29.2/bin","/nix/store/lb61dshvvqy1rgjhhlzaiiv2fv157lr5-stack-2.1.3.1/bin","/nix/store/71n1xcigc00w3z7yc836jqcx9cb2dys8-patchelf-0.9/bin","/nix/store/xhhkr936b9q5sz88jp4l29wljbbcg39k-ncurses-6.1-20190112/bin","/nix/store/khqyxflp8wbq038wdyv5sr8sjsfwlr72-llvm-9.0.1/bin","/nix/store/84g84bg47xxg01ba3nv0h418v5v3969n-ncurses-6.1-20190112-dev/bin","/nix/store/xhhkr936b9q5sz88jp4l29wljbbcg39k-ncurses-6.1-20190112/bin","/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/bin","/nix/store/97vambzyvpvrd9wgrrw7i7svi0s8vny5-findutils-4.7.0/bin","/nix/store/dqq1bvpi3g0h4v05111b3i0ymqj4v5x1-diffutils-3.7/bin","/nix/store/p34p7ysy84579lndk7rbrz6zsfr03y71-gnused-4.8/bin","/nix/store/b0vjq4r4sp9z4l2gbkc5dyyw5qfgyi3r-gnugrep-3.4/bin","/nix/store/c8balm59sxfkw9ik1fqbkadsvjqhmbx4-gawk-5.0.1/bin","/nix/store/g7dr83wnkx4gxa5ykcljc5jg04416z60-gnutar-1.32/bin","/nix/store/kkvgr3avpp7yd5hzmc4syh43jqj03sgb-gzip-1.10/bin","/nix/store/rw96psqzgyqrcd12qr6ivk9yiskjm3ab-bzip2-1.0.6.0.1-bin/bin","/nix/store/dp6y0n9cba79wwc54n1brg7xbjsq5hka-gnumake-4.2.1/bin","/nix/store/hrpvwkjz04s9i4nmli843hyw9z4pwhww-bash-4.4-p23/bin","/nix/store/xac1zfclx1xxgcd84vqb6hy3apl171n8-patch-2.7.6/bin","/nix/store/mm0w8jc58rn01c4kz2n9jvwd6bibcihs-xz-5.2.4-bin/bin"]
```

Other things worth noting: I tried everything stack related with two resolvers: lts-14.0 which was already there and nightly-2020-01-30 which was recently added in a commit to llvm-hs, but same result.

Also tried changing llvm-hs version restrictions to include the latest 9.0.1 in llvm-hs-examples' cabal file, but same result.

I'm on NixOS channel 20.03

If you want me to share or try something else, please let me know, and thank you for your help.

Lastly, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?  They might be able to shed more light on where a `JITSymbolError ""` could come from...

Comment: I did, via an issue in his llvm-hs-examples github repo. Maybe I should try contacting him through other methods